# What is the % Branch column for in solidity-coverage?

Tags: hardhat, solidity-coverage, coverage

In the [solidity-coverage](https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage) package output, there is a column called `% Branch`, what is it for?

```
yarn hardhat coverage
```

Output:

```
---------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File                       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
---------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
 contracts/                |       95 |     87.5 |    84.62 |       95 |                |
  Raffle.sol               |       95 |     87.5 |    84.62 |       95 |        153,157 |
 contracts/test/           |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
  LinkToken.sol            |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
  VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
---------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files                  |       95 |     87.5 |    84.62 |       95 |                |
---------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

The other columns make sense, but not the `% Branch`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, it's the % of the control statements that are covered..

The idea of branch comes from the conditional statement like if-else, switch-case... each of the conditional matchings is the branch.

[image: branch]

In the code, it's something like:

```
if (a.isANumber) {
   // branch 1
} else {
   // branch 2
}
```

Comment: So, is it the % of if-else statements that are covered?

Comment: Basically it's the % of the control statement. Including if-else